# Why my app is only showing loading screen? and warn me TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_asyncStorage.AsyncStorage.getItem')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why my app is only showing loading screen? when i am running my app than its only loading and not showing other screens and showing a  WARN  that

` WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is

i think it has problem with this code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import  { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import * as authActions from '../store/actions/auth';

const StartupScreen = props => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        const tryLogin = async () => {
            const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
            if (!userData) {
                // props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
                dispatch(authActions.setDidTryAutoLogin());
                return;
            }
            const transformedData = JSON.parse(userData);
            const { token, user } = transformedData;

            // props.navigation.navigate('Shop');
            dispatch(authActions.authenticate(user, token));
        };

        tryLogin();
}, [dispatch])


return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.primary} />
    </View>
);
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default StartupScreen;
```

Comment: Show less of the error and more of the code. How is imported? The error pretty much says it: AsyncStorage is not an object, meaning no getItem is available.

Comment: @Zarko checkit out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage#importing) you import is wrong.

This:

```js
import  { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

should be

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Basically, what you are trying to do with `{AsyncStorage}` is you are importing "part" of the exported code called `AsyncStorage`. That is why the error says:
`_asyncStorage.AsyncStorage.getItem')` (`asyncStorage` mentioned twice) and you need the entire object out of the package.

Comment: one more error  ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoNotifications.default.addListener') this time i am importing like thisimport * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

Comment: pls check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486905/how-to-deal-with-these-errors-error-typeerror-notifications-addlistener-is-not