# How to deal with these errors ERROR TypeError: Notifications.addListener is not a function. (In 'Notifications.addListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Can anyone can help me to fix these errors this is a little bit old project earlier i was importing notifications from expo but due to react-native updates i am importing it from expo-notifications because their is no notification pre-build in expo

WARN  expo-permissions is now deprecated — the functionality has been moved to other expo packages that directly use these permissions (e.g. expo-location, expo-camera). The package will be removed in the upcoming releases

ERROR  TypeError: Notifications.addListener is not a function. (In 'Notifications.addListener(_handleNotification)', 'Notifications.addListener' is undefined)

My File:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Image,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Vibration,
    Platform,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';

import { showMessage } from "react-native-flash-message";
import * as authActions from '../../store/actions/auth';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Colors from '../../constants/Colors';

import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


const AuthScreen = (props) => {

    const [isSignup, setIsSignUp] = useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState('');
    const [notification, setNotification] = useState({});

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let token;
    let _notificationSubscription;

    const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
        if (Constants.isDevice) {
            const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
            let finalStatus = existingStatus;
            if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
                const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
                finalStatus = status;
            }
            if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Failed !',
                    'Failed to get push token for push notification!',
                    [{ text: 'Okay' }]
                );
                return;
            }
            try{
                token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
            } catch(err){
                showMessage({
                    message: `ERROR - ${err.message}`,
                    description: `${err}`,
                    type: "danger",
                    icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                    duration: 3000
                });
            }
            console.log(token);
            setExpoPushToken(token);
        } else {
            Alert.alert(
                'Error !',
                'Must use physical device for Push Notifications',
                [{ text: 'Okay' }]
            )
        }
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('default', {
                name: 'default',
                sound: true,
                priority: 'max',
                vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
        console.log(expoPushToken);
        _notificationSubscription = Notifications.addListener(_handleNotification);
    }, [])
        

    const _handleNotification = notification => {
        Vibration.vibrate();
        setNotification(notification);
    };






    const validateAuthForm = () => {
        const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        const passwordRegex = /\d/
        if(isSignup && !name){
            showMessage({
                message: "Please enter a valid name.",
                type: "danger",
                icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                duration: 3000
            });
            setIsLoading(false);
            return false;
        }
        if(isSignup && name && name.length < 2){
            showMessage({
                message: "Please enter a valid name.",
                type: "danger",
                icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                duration: 3000
            });
            setIsLoading(false);
            return false;
        }
        if(!emailRegex.test(email.toLowerCase())){
            showMessage({
                message: "Please enter a valid email.",
                type: "danger",
                icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                duration: 3000
            });
            setIsLoading(false);
            return false;
        }
        if(!password || password.length === 0){
            showMessage({
                message: "Please enter your password.",
                type: "danger",
                icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                duration: 3000
            });
            setIsLoading(false);
            return false;
        }
        if(isSignup && password.length < 6){
            showMessage({
                message: "Password should be atleast 6 characters long.",
                type: "danger",
                icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                duration: 3000
            });
            setIsLoading(false);
            return false;

        }
        if(isSignup && !passwordRegex.test(password)){
            showMessage({
                message: "Password should contain atleast 1 number.",
                type: "danger",
                icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                duration: 3000
            });
            setIsLoading(false);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    const AuthHandler = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        if(validateAuthForm()){
            if(isSignup){
                try {
                    const msg = await dispatch(authActions.signup(name, email, password, expoPushToken))
                    showMessage({
                        message: "Signup Success",
                        description: 'Please Login !',
                        type: "success",
                        icon: { icon: "success", position: 'left' },
                        duration: 3000
                    });
                    setIsSignUp(false);
                    setName('');
                    setEmail('');
                    setPassword('');
                } catch (error) {
                    showMessage({
                        message: error.message,
                        type: "danger",
                        icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                        duration: 3000
                    });
                }
                setIsLoading(false);
            } else {
                try {
                    await dispatch(authActions.signin(email, password, expoPushToken))
                    showMessage({
                        message: "Signed in success",
                        type: "success",
                        icon: { icon: "success", position: 'left' },
                        duration: 3000
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    showMessage({
                        message: error.message,
                        type: "danger",
                        icon: { icon: "danger", position: 'left' },
                        duration: 3000
                    });
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const inputChangeHandler = (text,inputField) => {
        if(inputField === 1){
            setName(text)
        } else if(inputField === 2){
            setEmail(text)
        } else if(inputField === 3){
            setPassword(text)
        }
    }


    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.bgImage} source={require('../../assets/bg-auth.png')} />
                <View style={styles.titleContainer} >
                    <Text style={styles.title}>SocialApp</Text>
                </View>

                {/* { error !== null && (
                    <View style={styles.errorMsgContainer} >
                        <Image style={styles.msgIcon} source={{ uri: "https://i.imgur.com/GnyDvKN.png" }} />
                        <Text style={styles.msgText}> {error} </Text>
                    </View>
                )} */}

                { isSignup && (
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                            placeholder="Name"
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            value={name}
                            onChangeText={(text) => inputChangeHandler(text,1)}
                        />
                        <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/40/000000/name.png' }} />
                    </View>
                ) }
                
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                        placeholder="Email"
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        value={email}
                        onChangeText={(text) => inputChangeHandler(text, 2) }
                    />
                    <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/40/000000/email.png' }} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        value={password}
                        onChangeText={(text) => inputChangeHandler(text, 3) }
                    />
                    <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/40/000000/key.png' }} />
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword')}
                    style={styles.btnForgotPassword} 
                >
                    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Forgot your password?</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}
                    onPress={AuthHandler}
                >

                    { isLoading ? (
                        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />
                    )  :(
                        <Text style={styles.loginText}>
                            { isSignup ? "Register" : "Login" }
                        </Text>
                    ) }
                    
                </TouchableOpacity>


                <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.registerButton]}
                    onPress={() => {
                        setIsSignUp(prevState => !prevState);
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.btnText} >
                        { isSignup ? "Already a user ? Login" : "Don't have an account ? Register" }
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>    
    );
}


export const screenOptions = (navData) => {
    return{
        headerTitle: 'Auth',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly familiar with Expo, but it doesn't seem like the function `addListener` you are trying to call actually exists in `expo-notifications`. At least there's no reference to it in [the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/). Since you say it is an older project, that function has probably be renamed to something else.

You're most likely looking for one of the `addNotification*Listener` functions described on that page. From my gut feeling, I'd try with `Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener`. Still, to find out which one it really is you need, you would need to share more info about where you found out about `Notifications.addListener` in the first place.

Comment: this code is not written by me that is the issue its a little bit old project and you are true that addListener is not a function in new versions of expo So now what to do? what to write in place of addListener?

Comment: As I said, I don't know that much about Expo, so this is just guesswork, but from the docs, you have three options and given your code, I think `Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener` will probably be it. If that doesn't work, try with `Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener`

Comment: Always glad to help, take care and have fun!